# Trying to write a MacOS automator script to make incrementing folders based off of scanned input

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, automator

New to bash scripting, and I'm stuck. Within a static directory I'm trying to create a folder '001_scanned name' and within that directory create 6 more subfolders. I'm able to do it all brutishly with this code:

```
cd ~/deej/Test/Capture
mkdir "$1"
cd "$1"
mkdir "$1_1"
mkdir "$1_2"
mkdir "$1_3"
mkdir "$1_4"
mkdir "$1_5"
mkdir "$1_6"
```

Ugly, but works for now.

$1 is the scanned name and I was manually appending the prefix of the file names with "001, 002, etc.". Is there an easy way to do this within an Automator prompt since I'll be unable to keep the last variable stored in the code?

Comment: [The desired output.](https://ibb.co/1d2HdZR)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `-p` option with `mkdir` it will create intermediate directories as needed so you can do both commands at once. The `seq` function can create zero-padded integers:

```
for n in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 10); 
   do mkdir -p ${i}/${i}_${n}; 
done;
```

You can test using `echo` instead of `mkdir -p`. Below I had `i` set to `015`...

```
015/015_001
015/015_002
015/015_003
015/015_004
015/015_005
015/015_006
015/015_007
015/015_008
015/015_009
015/015_010
```